# Query lookups in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy

I can’t find any information about lookup api in the SQLAlchemy, is it supported?

I’m talking about this feature in Django ORM: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/lookups/

It’s very useful for my case because I have a table on frontend with many filtering options, and in Django I can just `queryset.filter(**kwargs)`.

If this is not supported, is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

In SQLAlchemy 1.4 you can do `Query.filter_by(**kwargs)`, if this is what you are looking for. ([docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.filter_by))

I don't know if this API made it into 2.0.

EDIT:
It seems in 2.0 they added another layer of abstraction and now it's `Select.filter_by(**kwargs)`([docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.filter_by))

Comment: It looks similar but is it only allows to find exact matches? I mean, what if I need to filter where `some_field > 0`, for example

Comment: For boolean expressions you can use `Query.filter(MyClass.some_field > 0)` or more general `Query.filter(*filter_criteria)`. (It's the entry in the docs directly above `filter_by`)